# Highcharts manually setting legendItemClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I need to set the plotOptions -> events -> legendItemClick but manually on button click.

I though it would be something like chart.plotOptions.events.legendItemClick = function() {...}; but that obviously wasn't the solution.

I am not even sure if this is possible and I have to implement it on chart creation ONLY.

Any guidance on this is much appreciated. Thanks.

Setting in highcharts via creation:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        events: {
            legendItemClick: function() {
                // Do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do... (Post creation)

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts(); // Get the highcharts

// This doesn't work
chart.plotOptions.series.legendItemClick = function() { // Set the legendItemClick
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. You can set the `legendItemClick` function to do something you want, yes. But, without seeing code we do not know what that something is. I think what you want is to fire the legendItemClick when you click on an HTML button?

Comment: declaring it when creating the highcharts isn't the issue. I want to declare it post creation. The question isn't what I do inside the event legendItemClick it is how do I set that via the chart variable when doing this for instance. var chart = $('#container').highcharts(); chart.plotOptions.series.legendItemClick = function() { ... }; that method doesn't work and need to know if it is possible to do it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We do it but within the `legendItemClick` itself. This work for us as we only have 2 states. The first is the initial load where we let the chart built with default legend click actions (all series are visible, clicking on a series in the legend hides that series, clicking on that series again shows it). The other state is when a user has selected a display option in a ddl that removes all but one series as being visible and then the user can click on a legend item and *only* show that item. We do it like:

```
function(event) {
    var e = document.getElementById('" & gModeElementId & "');
    var strGraphMode = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    if (strGraphMode == 'single') {
        var seriesIndex = this.index;
        var serie = this.chart.series;
        for (i = 0; i < serie.length; i++) {
            if (serie[i].index == seriesIndex) {
                serie[i].show();
                var ctitle = this.chart.yAxis[0].axisTitle;
                ctitle.attr({text: serie[i].name});
            } else {
            serie[i].hide();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

We also have not found a way to actually modify an existing `legendItemClick` function.

Comment: "We also have not found a way to actually modify an existing legendItemClick function." exactly the answer I was looking for, not hoping for however. Thank you for the detailed answer. I guess I will have to work out another strategy.

Comment: I should note that we build this out from a .NET backend (hence `getElementById('" & gModeElementId & "')`). So if you do that you can have function dynamically built out. Or, have the `legendItemClick` function be some other function you write on the page. But, yes, it is a create once and deal with it thing unfortunately.

Comment: The this.chart.series part was useful to me. Thanks!